# How to run my code on an ARM _without_ debugging?

Tags: eclipse, embedded, arm

I've been developing a project (in C) for an STM32F105, using the Eclipse IDE with CDT plugins.  I'm using the gcc-arm toolchain, OpenOCD (gdb) for debugging, and an ST-Link/V2 JTAG device.

I've been debugging on my target board, no problems.

Now, I finally want the code to run by itself, and I don't know how to do it in Eclipse!  I'm sure it's simple, but I can't find it.

How do I build the code and program my target so that it runs "normally"?

Comment: Unless you are running from ram (which is less likely, as it imposes limitations) chances are just resetting the board without the debugger connected or active will start whatever you last flashed.  Otherwise you can use the open source stlink tools to flash.

Comment: Please share further information regarding your target board and the related on-board peripherals.

Comment: Generally, in some systems, you may need to invoke the application via bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure OpenOCD as external tool and use arguments more or less like these:

`-f interface/... -f target/... -c "init; reset init; flash write_image erase <your_hex_file.hex>; reset run; shutdown;"`

You should of course adapt this command to your project: enter proper interface and target configs and set right name of hex file (you can also use .bin or .elf, but .hex is usually the most convenient).

In the "Working Directory" textbox enter your project directory - use "Browse Workspace" to do that, you should have sth like this there: `${workspace_loc:/<name_of_your_project>}`

Comment: Thanks Freddie, you got me much closer.  When I do this, OpenOCD transfers the file properly, but then says the target has halted due to a breakpoint, and it doesn't run.  I tried a Release build instead of a Debug build, with the same result.  I'll remove the breakpoints and see what happens, although I expect there is a method to automatically discard the breakpoint settings from a build. Do you have any hints for me? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One of my projects worked by simply disconnecting the debugger and resetting the target, as suggested by @ChrisStratton.  The other didn't, whether I used the IDE or the ST-LINK tools.  It worked fine when the debugger was attached.

It turns out that the non-working program was using semi-hosting.  When I disabled semi-hosting by removing the following compiler symbols, the project started running just fine on its own.

[image]